# set two values for an input name attribute

Tags: php, html

i have a check box list that some limited check boxes can be selected. for this i set the name attr of all them "answer" to work with the js function properly(i got the function from some where).

```
<?php
else if($result['type'] == "multipleChoice"){
echo'
<div><input type="checkbox" name="answer ans1" value="'.$res['probAns1'].'"/><input type="text" class="prob-ans" name="prob-ans1" value="'.$res['probAns1'].'"/><lable>:گزینه 1</lable></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="answer ans2" value="'.$res['probAns2'].'"/><input type="text" class="prob-ans" name="prob-ans2" value="'.$res['probAns2'].'"/><lable>:گزینه 2</lable></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="answer ans3" value="'.$res['probAns3'].'"/><input type="text" class="prob-ans" name="prob-ans3" value="'.$res['probAns3'].'"/><lable>:گزینه 3</lable></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="answer ans4" value="'.$res['probAns4'].'"/><input type="text" class="prob-ans" name="prob-ans4" value="'.$res['probAns4'].'"/><lable>:گزینه 4</lable></div>
';  
?>
```

first is it correct to set two value for name attr. i did it but didnt work. like it isnt acceptable the second value.
if not how can i specify them if i have just name="answer"? i want to set some values in php if one of these check boxes is set.

```
<?php
if($result['type'] == "multipleChoice"){
    $question->probAns1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['prob-ans1']);
    $question->probAns2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['prob-ans2']);
    $question->probAns3 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['prob-ans3']);
    $question->probAns4 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['prob-ans4']);
    if(isset($_POST['ans1'])){
        $question->answer1 = $_POST['prob-ans1'];
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Use proper capitalization of words when asking a question. It makes texts more readable.

Comment: Setting `name="answer ans1"` does not assign two names. It assigns a single name, containing a space character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't have two names like you did. Following however is possible:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="answer[]" value="abc" />
<input type="checkbox" name="answer[]" value="def" />
```

Your `$_POST` will look like following (if both are checked):

```
array(
    'answer' => array(
        0 =>      'abc',
        1 =>      'def'
    )
)
```

You can also specify the array-keys, thus `name="answer[answ1]" value="abc"` will give you `$_POST['answer']['answ1'] == 'abc'`

Comment: Tanx, It fixed my problem but i have a new one.
`
<script type="text/javascript">    checkboxlimit(document.forms.createQuestion.answer, 2);
</script>
`
The function "checkboxlimit" is called at the end BODY. It doesnt work anymore. I changed **document.forms.createQuestion.answer** to **document.forms.createQuestion.answer[]**. But no luck!

Answer (score -2):

Here is [link](http://www.wastedpotential.com/html-multi-checkbox-set-the-correct-way-to-group-checkboxes/) of what you need to do.

In one sentence, you need to use arrays of html elements.

Comment: A link alone is not an adequate answer. “Arrays of html elements” is a vague concept and does not say how this relates to the question.